# Sort a 2D array by the length of the inner array descending?

Tags: python, arrays

Is there a very pythonistic way to sort a 2d array by length of the inner array? For example turn this:

```
[]
[[23, 70, 90]]
[[23, 70, 90], [48, 56, 99]]
[[23, 70, 90], [48, 56, 99], [79, 89, 91]]
[[23, 70, 90], [79, 89, 91]]
[[48, 56, 99]]
[[48, 56, 99], [79, 89, 91]]
[[79, 89, 91]]
```

Into:

```
[[23, 70, 90], [48, 56, 99], [79, 89, 91]]
[[23, 70, 90], [48, 56, 99]]
[[23, 70, 90], [79, 89, 91]]
[[48, 56, 99], [79, 89, 91]]
[[23, 70, 90]]
[[48, 56, 99]]
[[79, 89, 91]]
[]
```

Surely there is one line of code to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surely there is! Python's sort has a `key` optional parameter which allows passing in a function to operate on and return some modified version of each item in the list to use for sorting.

The long-winded but easy to read way would be to define a function and pass it that:

```py
def x(e):
    return len(e)

my_list.sort(key=x)
```

but the one-liner way is to use a lambda (full working example down yonder):

```py
l = [[],
[[23, 70, 90]],
[[23, 70, 90], [48, 56, 99]],
[[23, 70, 90], [48, 56, 99], [79, 89, 91]],
[[23, 70, 90], [79, 89, 91]],
[[48, 56, 99]],
[[48, 56, 99], [79, 89, 91]],
[[79, 89, 91]]]

def print_arr(a):
    for x in a:
        print(x)

print_arr(l)

# here she is!
l.sort(key=lambda x: len(x)) # add the optional 'reverse=True' param if desired

print_arr(l)
```

Comment: Awesome works like a charm! I noticed the key parameter but I wasn't sure exactly how to use it, Thank for your help!